# Error while sending an Email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, send, smtpclient

I am trying send email using codeigniter function.
I have try this code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();


}
 function index()
{
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('praju.rade@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
    $this->email->to('praju.rade@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

}
?>

---

I got this error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "smtp.wlink.com.np" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"
>   setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1553

Comment: is it hosted in godaddy??

Comment: The error message is pretty precise. So what is the question?

Comment: A simple DNS lookup reveals that the MX records for that hostname point to `mx-03.wlink.com.np` or `mx-04.wlink.com.np`. So you probably want to use those in your settings instead.

Comment: Where is your controller class?

Answer (score 1):

The error message helps a little to know what happens. You can contact your supplier to provide you information on the SMTP server or set your preferences mail CodeIgniter to not use SMTP they use the native PHP mail function
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences

You could also use the Gmail SMTP
http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-gmail-smtp/